# Are questions of the form "Is X discussed in Jewish sources" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy

On the one hand, there are several legitimate questions that can be phrased in this manner. Off the top of my head, there are several already on board, regarding [aliens](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens), [vampires](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26593/are-there-any-jewish-sources-that-discuss-vampires), [werewolves](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/werewolf-in-the-torah), [time travel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/time-travel-and-judaism), [babies being born without teeth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/is-it-discussed-why-a-baby-is-born-without-teeth), [Migdal Bavel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/is-the-tower-of-babel-discussed-in-other-jewish-texts), [the elements](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30005/what-does-judaism-have-to-say-about-the-origin-of-elements), [graphology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53478/graphology-sources-that-permit-or-forbid-it)... The list goes on and on.

But that the list goes on and on is precisely the problem. At what point do we draw the line of what sort of question is on-topic and what sort of question should be "taken out and taught outside"?

Comment: Can you give an example of a question of this type you think should not be allowed?

Comment: Motivation and scope can make a difference here.  "I read in such-and-such commentary that the talmud talks about space aliens; is that true and if so where?" is different from "do any Jewish sources talk about people with green hair?".  A question to ask about the question is: is there any plausible reason to think Jewish sources *would* say something about that?  (No time for an answer now so just dropping this here as food for thought.  (CYR for kashrut status of comments before eating.)

Comment: That's a fair point Monica. But say that the two questions are of identical scope, but one is "Do any Jewish sources talk about aliens" (evidently permitted) and the other is "Do any Jewish sources talk about doors" (I would assume ridiculous enough to get closed down). So at what point in between do we say no?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/ridiculous-questions http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/is-a-question-that-asks-what-does-judaism-think-of-x-possibly-off-topic

Comment: Is this really different from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2160? That's "what's Judaism's take on discussion X" and this is "what's Judaism's take on item X". cc @IsaacMoses

Comment: @msh210, I agree, and seeing neither answers nor dissent, I'll go ahead and dupe this.